# Cannot find type definition file for "jquery"

Tags: jquery, node.js

I'm getting an error in Visual Studio 2015 when I try to compile my WebAPI project:

"Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery'"

I'm setting up my project using node.js.

The main folder for the project is RiskAlive9, and under that folder is a set of sub-projects:

- Core
- Database
- Test
- Web
- WebAPI

Everything compiles properly except for WebAPI which is giving me the error above.

Here's how I installed node, bower, and typescript:

```
npm install
```

This created a node_modules folder in the main folder (RiskAlive9).

```
npm install -g bower
```

This installed bower, gulp, and a bunch of pluggins for gulp.

```
bower install
```

This created a bower_components folder in the main folder (RiskAlive9).

```
npm install typescript@2.4.1
```

This installed typescript 2.4.1

```
npm install "@types/jquery"
```

This created a @types folder in the node_modules folder with a jquery folder inside it.

Yet WebAPI is still saying it cannot find the type definition file for jquery.

So I tried copying node_modules into the WebAPI folder. This fixed 99% of the errors (cannot find type definition file was not the only one), but also brought up a few new errors.

I'm wondering: does installing node typically mean installing it for every project in your solution (such that each sub-folder that needs to use node will have a node_modules folder)? Or isn't there a way to get all projects in your solution to use the main node_modules folder?